# dplyr get a group-level variable from the lagged group

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a df with groups and a group-level variable like a mean. How do I produce a variable which is the group-level mean of the lagged group, where the only rows with NA for this variable are those in the first group?

e.g:

```
df <- data_frame(group = c(1,1,2,2),
             grouped.mean = c(2.5,2.5,3.5,3.5))

# my attempt
df %<>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(lag.group.mean = lag(grouped.mean))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group grouped.mean lag.group.mean
  <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1    1.         2.50          NA   
2    1.         2.50           2.50
3    2.         3.50          NA   
4    2.         3.50           3.50
```

Desired output:

```
  group grouped.mean lag.group.mean
  <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1    1.         2.50          NA   
2    1.         2.50          NA
3    2.         3.50          2.50   
4    2.         3.50          2.50
```

Thanks!

EDIT: more challenging example:

```
df <- data_frame(group = c(1,1,2,3,3,3),
                 grouped.mean = c(2.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,4.5,4.5))
```

expected output:

```
  group grouped.mean lag.grouped.mean
  <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>
1    1.         2.50            NA   
2    1.         2.50            NA   
3    2.         3.50            2.50
4    3.         4.50            3.50
5    3.         4.50            3.50
6    3.         4.50            3.50
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option. The key is to use `distinct` to remove duplicated rows, create the `lag.group.mean` column, and then `left_join` to the original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(group = c(1,1,2,2),
                 grouped.mean = c(2.5,2.5,3.5,3.5))

df2 <- df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(lag.group.mean = lag(grouped.mean)) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = c("group", "grouped.mean"))
df2
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   group grouped.mean lag.group.mean
#   <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1     1          2.5           NA  
# 2     1          2.5           NA  
# 3     2          3.5            2.5
# 4     2          3.5            2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

The lagged group value is the first globally lagged value within each group:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(group = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                 grouped.mean = c(2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5))

df %>% 
  mutate(lag.grouped.mean = lag(grouped.mean)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(lag.grouped.mean = first(lag.grouped.mean))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   group grouped.mean lag.grouped.mean
#>   <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1     1          2.5             NA  
#> 2     1          2.5             NA  
#> 3     2          3.5              2.5
#> 4     3          4.5              3.5
#> 5     3          4.5              3.5
#> 6     3          4.5              3.5
```

But it's probably easier to see what's happening if you use a join like in
[@www's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51700905/4550695).

Created on 2018-08-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).